# Parse a bitmap from Parcel

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to parse google maps notification. I managed to parse all the lines.
The problem that I need to parse the image that google maps defines through it the direction of the next maneuver. I have excption "java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to unparcel Bitmap" using the below code.

```
   if (sbn.getPackageName().equals("com.google.android.apps.maps")){
         Notification not = sbn.getNotification();
         RemoteViews views = (RemoteViews) not.bigContentView;
         List<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();
            try
               {
                Field field = views.getClass().getDeclaredField("mActions");
                 field.setAccessible(true);

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                 ArrayList<Parcelable> actions = (ArrayList<Parcelable>) field.get(views);

                 // Find the setText() and setTime() reflection actions
                   for (Parcelable p : actions)
                       {
                       Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
                       p.writeToParcel(parcel, 0);
                       parcel.setDataPosition(0);

                // The tag tells which type of action it is (2 is ReflectionAction, from the source)
                 int tag = parcel.readInt();
                  if ( ( tag != 2 ) && ( tag != 12 )) {
                         continue;
                      }

                   // View ID
                   parcel.readInt();
                    String methodName = parcel.readString();
                    if (methodName == null){
                          continue;
                        }else if (methodName.equals("setImageBitmap")){
                        parcel.setDataPosition(0);
                        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel);
                              sendBroadcast(i2);
                       }
                       // Save strings
              else if (methodName.equals("setText"))
              {
                 // Parameter type (10 = Character Sequence)
                   parcel.readInt();

                   // Store the actual string
                String t = TextUtils.CHAR_SEQUENCE_CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel).toString().trim();
               text.add(t);
                }
        // Save times. Comment this section out if the notification time isn't important
          else if (methodName.equals("setTime"))
               {
                   // Parameter type (5 = Long)
                   parcel.readInt();

                  String t = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a").format(new Date(parcel.readLong()));
                   text.add(t);
               }
                  parcel.recycle();

            }
      }

  // It's not usually good style to do this, but then again, neither is the use of reflection...
  catch (Exception e)
   {
     Log.e("NotificationClassifier", e.toString());
   }
 }
```

Edit: I do not care about memory now plus I am reading google map image not sending Image from an activity to another.

Comment: System `Bitmap` doesn't implement `parceble`, so you can't unparce it. And don't extend `Bitmap` to implement it, just don't, please. You'll run into huge memory problems.

Comment: So If I want to get the direction from google maps notification...What do u propose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're doing the same thing I am or similar. In any case, I was struggling as well with the same task. If you don't have anything against using libraries, this worked perfectly for me. I ran it on the normal ContentView though it might also work on BigContentView.

Just slightly modify this if needed and it should work.

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = sbn.getNotification().contentView;
RemoteViewsInfo info = RemoteViewsReader.read(this, sbn.getNotification().contentView);
RemoteViewsInfo info = RemoteViewsReader.read(this, remoteViews);
for (RemoteViewsAction action : info.getActions()) {
  if (!(action instanceof BitmapReflectionAction))
    continue;
  BitmapReflectionAction concrete = (BitmapReflectionAction)action;
  Bitmap bmp = concrete.getBitmap();
}
```

https://github.com/KeithYokoma/RemoteViewsReader

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

So, as I said, you shoudn't place `Bitmap` into `Parcel` or `Bundle`, this will result significant slow down of your app and possible memory problem.

### What should you do

If you really need to pass image from one place to another - save it. Just create temp file and pass path to this temp file wherever you want.

### How can you get bitmap from notification?

Can you?

After some thinking, I bet you just can't do that. But, what you can do - it's screen capture. Try to find where is that ImageView placed and capture the screen part. Then do what ever you want.

Comment: That is actually my question.
How to do that?

Answer (score -1):

try to pass Byte[] from drawable across parcel

**BUT:**

- @vamp you see, pass huge amount of bytes in Bundle or Parcel is not really recommended. This will not only slow down your app, but also can result memory problems.*

Comment: Don't ever do it in real app. Please.

Comment: @Ekalips
I am doing it for personal purpose but why?

Comment: @vamp you see, pass huge amount of bytes in `Bundle` or `Parcel` is not really recommended. This will not only slow down your app, but also can result memory problems.

Comment: I am not passing in parcel. I have to use parcel as it is the way to read google maps notification